# Flutter: aligning buttons edge to edge to other components

Tags: button, flutter, layout, alignment

I found it difficult to layout buttons in a way that their visual representation is harmonic with other widgets, yet their touchable area has additional extra space for users' fingers.

Please have a look at the attached picture.

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(child: HomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Top Left'),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text('Top right')
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Middle Left'),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text('Middle right')
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Bottom Left'),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text('Bottom right')
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Top Left'),
                    Spacer(),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Top right'),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Middle Left'),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text('Middle right')
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.print),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text('Bottom right')
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The "all texts" widgets are beautifully aligned. But when I add interactive widgets, it starts getting ugly.

The Flat button has the same font as Text. But it's touchable area is expanding it. I am aware of `materialTapTargetSize` but it shrinks the clickable area which has its inflated size to make it easy to tap it. Is there an easy way to render it exactly as the "Top right" text widget and still have the same touchable area? In that case, the touchable area should expand further out of 16px padding, because I would link the Ink to be distributed evently around the button.

IconButton is higher than text, but the problem is that it doesn't start where the texts starts (left edge). Even if I add the `alignment: Alignment.centerLeft`, it is slightly moved to the left but still not edge to edge with other texts. On top of that after changing this alignment it's no longer centred within its InkWell.

For now, I solve all these issues using Stack and Positioned widgets. With this approach, I can control exactly where the items are, and the InkWell keeps the content exactly in the centre. But I believe it's not a correct solution.

Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

**For the flat button:**

```
Container(
   alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
   width: 60,
   child: FlatButton(
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
     child: Text('Top right'),
     onPressed: () {},
   ),
)
```

**For the icon button:**

```
IconButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  icon: Icon(Icons.print),
  onPressed: () {},
  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
),
```

Comment: I've mentioned in my original post that I know some of these tricks already. The flat button looks better, but still expands the content vertically and its tappable area got smaller (harder to tap). The Icon button is very out of the centre when selected. I am attaching the result here https://imgur.com/a/oTKb6KW (combined image of both buttons highlighted, I also used MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap).

Comment: use the container, inside that container, set the height and width for that child. It'll work.